# bison says invalid option --

Tags: bash

I'm using flex and bison in Mac OS Maverick.  I can send the bison and flex command in bash without any problem.  But when I tried to issue the command using a shell script.  I got this error.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bison: invalid option -- 
Try `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bison --help' for more information.
flex: can't open minus.l
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'minus.tab.c'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'lex.yy.c'
: No such file or directoryut
```

The script is as follows:

```
bison minus.y -d
flex minus.l
gcc minus.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -ly
```

Answer (score 2):

Your script has DOS line endings. `bash` is interpreting the carriage return as a regular character. `flex` is actually trying to open `minus.l\r`, not `minus.l`, and notice the odd last error message:

```
: No such file or directoryut
```

There should be a path name, followed by `: No such file or directory`, but since the path name ends in `\r`, the cursor is moved back to the beginning of the line and the error message overwrites all but the last two characters of the path (`ut`).

Remove the carriage returns using `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is missing a header

```
#!/bin/bash
bison minus.y -d
flex minus.l
gcc minus.tab.c lex.yy.c -lfl -ly
```

if that does not solve the problem, you might want to look at the line (endings) (using `od -c` or `xxd`) to make sure there are no hidden characters (like CR/`^M`/`\r`) in the file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I added the shebang and got the error `-bash: ./makeparser: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. I suspected that it might be from the encoding.  So I created a new script using vi.  The file size of the new one is 4 bytes smaller.  I hexdump and found that the original file is from Windows.  The new script from vi works with and without the shebang.

Comment: @wannik Sometimes even a wrong answer can make you take a second look ;-) . I incorporated your comment in my answer, so that someone stumblink upon the Q doesn't have to go through the fine print of the comments to look for that solution.